# Regex words with letters, numbers, optional special characters in any order

Tags: regex, vba

I need to pick out whole words which contain at least 6 letters and/or numbers (combined, not each), with optional 'special' characters. All in any order, so `A12345`, `12345A`, `1-2-345-A`, `12A45B` and so-on.

This is VBA so no access to look behinds. The special characters will only ever be 'within' the match, not start or end (will never be `-1234-A-` for example).

Comment: I think you can just split the string and check each item in the array for 6 letters/numbers to build the resulting array/collection. No need for a regex actually.

Comment: Your fiddle uses `[0-9-/]`, the `-/` part looks odd and regex101.com complains `/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)`. Could you please verify that this is correct?

Comment: `A12345CN` can be matched as `A1|2|3|4|5CN` (where `|` is used to explain how) which is why it gets picked up by `{5,}` but not by `{6,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
[a-z0-9/-]{6,}
```

That will match in any order `a to z` or `0 to 9` or `-` or `/` of at least 6.  Note the `-` is at the end of the character class.  You can have it in the middle but then need to escape it.  Also, `/` will need to be escaped if your delimiters are also `/`

**update**

As Wiktor noted this would also capture `------` which may not be what you want.  I would suggest simply cleaning out all optional characters, and then running the above regex.  I would delete my answer since I'm not providing exactly what was being asked, but it would be a workable solution so it may have value.

Comment: `[a-z0-9/-]{6,}` will also match `-----------`, or `----/-----` strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew whoops, you are right!  Don't you ever take time off from StackOverflow :) lol

Comment: I know the right regex answer for this, but it is ugly. The best approach here is non-regex one.

Comment: I'm trying some goofy solutions but everything is a big long mess.  I would agree that regex might not be the right choice.  I think simply stripping out the _optional_ characters and then a nice regex would be clean.

Comment: Right, then, it will be a piece of cake :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the quick replies. Just to confirm I don't want to take anything out of the matches. My example fiddle would be an e-mail subject so I loop through all the matches passing them to a SQL sproc looking up tables for that value, returning the result I want.

So the matches in the subject need to be keps as-is.

Comment: I would say just to see if you have a match, strip the optional characters, regex it, and then if you have the match: ship the _non_ stripped string

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regex replacement to remove all non letters/numbers, and then check that the length of the resulting string is 6 or more:

```
Dim input As String = "A-1234-B"
Dim pattern As String = "[^A-Za-z0-9]+"
Dim replacement As String = ""
Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)

Console.WriteLine(result.Length)   ' 6
```

### Demo